# Solve the following equation with combinatorics....

Tags: combinatorics

Please , can you help with this exercise with combinations , I have no idea: Find $n$ such that $\mathrm{C}^3_n=\mathrm{C}^{12}_n$.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear; do you want to find $n$ such that $\binom{3}{n}=\binom{12}{n}$? (Or perhaps you prefer the notation $\mathrm{C}^3_n=\mathrm{C}^{12}_n$.)

Comment: Yes, I prefer the second notation

Comment: You can use $$\binom nr =0$$ for $r>n$

Comment: I dont understand. Can you explain?

Comment: @MattPressland I have a feeling the equality is supposed to be $\binom{n}{3} = \binom{n}{12}$ since there are no nontrivial solutions to the one given.

Comment: I have an exercise related to polinomial expansion. And there is said that 4th coefficient is equal to 13th . "n" is unknown.

Comment: @SpamIAm So do I - using the C-notation, the original post (before my edit) said that the 3 and the 12 should be at the top - it's possible this means one should read $\mathrm{C}^3_n$ as $\binom{3}{n}$; I don't remember. Either way, my edit to the actual question reflects what the OP described.

Comment: @user123499 In relation to the comment you asked for an explanation for - if $r>n$, there are $0$ ways of choosing $r$ things from a set of $n$. If you're question is related to a polynomial expansion, it's unlikely you care about this, and instead you want $n$ such that the two numbers are equal and non-zero. It might be worth editing your question to include the exercise you are trying to solve.

Comment: In the binomial expansion (sqr(x)-1/x)n,{n is the power of the whole parantheses} the 4th coefficient is equal to the 13th. Determine the term that does not contain the variable x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from the OP describing the problem as a binomial expansion of (sqr(x)-1/x)n, it seems like the problem involves expanding $\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\!\!n}$. Under this interpretation, @SpamIAm is correct and solving the problem involves where $\displaystyle C^{n}_{3} = C^{n}_{12}$. To solve this, note that $\displaystyle C^{n}_{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$. So $\dfrac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = \dfrac{n!}{12!(n-12)!}$. Since the numerators are equal, this is only true if the denominators are equal. The obvious way to try and solve this is to set $3! = (n-12)!$ and $12! = (n-3)!$. Both equations tell us $n=15$.

To determine the term that does not contain the variable $x$, you need to find the single term $\displaystyle C^{15}_{k}(x^2)^{15-k}\left(-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\!\!k}$ where, once you evaluate, the exponents on $x^2$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}$ cancel each other out (are equal). This can be written as $2(15-k) = 30-2k = k$. Solving yields $k=10$. Substitution and evaluating yields the final answer. In general for this type of problem, be very careful with the coefficients of $x^2$ and $\dfrac{1}{x}$ as they usually contribute to the answer. Here you get $1^5$ and $(-1)^{10}$ which are both 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't understand you first , because I'm not used with notations of combinatoric expressions like you showed me, I ussualy solve by using letter C with coefficients above and at the bottom.

Comment: I edited my answer to replace the binomial symbols with C. Does that help clarify enough?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: That's the last question. You see when you said that the exponents cancel each other out, I cannot understand, because the base of the second power is -1/x. And , so , how did you do it? How could we equalize powers with different bases?

Comment: If you have $\frac{x^7}{x^7}$, you get 1 because all the copies of $x$ on top can with the copies of $x$ on the bottom. So if we look for the place where all the exponents on top $(30-2k)$ equal the exponents on the bottom $(k)$, then we can find the solution.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions and thank you a lot!:)

Comment: Not a problem. If this is the answer you are looking for, please select it is the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{n}{3}=\binom{n}{12}$$
$$\binom{n}{n-3}=\binom{n}{12}$$
$$n-3=12,n=15$$

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you are looking for an integer solution.

You have that
$$
\binom{3}{n}=\binom{12}{n},
$$
so you only need to check for $n=0,1,2,3$. And the winner is $0$.